# Can not find Model perspective in pentaho kettle spoon

Tags: pentaho, kettle, spoon

I am using `pentaho Data INtegration` `CE 5.1`.

i their docs they say about perspectives

http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpdi_user_guide%2Fconcept_pdi_modeling_perspective.html

but i only see the data integration perspective , there is no `Model` or `visualize perspective`

do i need to add addons for that

Answer (score 0):

In this link you can find the plugin to add this perspectives.
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/List+of+Available+Pentaho+Data+Integration+Plug-Ins